# asp.net mvc 4 bundles and explicit file includes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am very confused, I just started to work on the CSS for my ASP.NET MVC4 website and I don't fully understand what is happening.

Currently my mobile layout works but any changes to it causes one strange effect after another. (e.g. the forms not being displayed to the ajax-loader.gif constantly being displayed.)

I have the following in `.Layout.Mobile.cshtml`

> ```
>    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")  
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /> 
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" /> 
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" /> 
>
>
>     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile") 
>     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
> ```

I have modified the `BundleMobileConfig.cs` in App_start as follows:

```
 //       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mobile/css")
 //           .Include("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css"));
 //kludge is the above wrong...and the following needed??
         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mobile/css")
            .Include("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css",
                     "~/Content/Mobile/css/"));
```

I don't understand why this is NOT the default for this bundle?

Here are my questions / problems:

1. If you will note the stylesheets, I should not need to include the three explicit links, they should come from the bundles.  But if delete any of them the site breaks.

   - Why won't the modified `~/Content/Mobile/css` bundle pull up these css files?
2. For the script files I have looked at the code.jquery.com and I don't understand why I need these. My local code is the latest (i.e. jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js

   - I would expect that the version 1.9.1 shoud be able to replace the 1.7.1 without
         problems, but it doesn't
   - The jquery.mobile.min.js should only be switching between a release and debug
        vesion, which should not cause a problem, but it does.

I have used firebug to view what files are being loaded and I see that when I use just
the Render of the bundles without the explicit includes I don't get the files included, why not?  I have read about bundles and it seems like I should just get the bundled files.

Can any one shed some light on what is happening and point me to a tutorial so I can learn
how to use how to debug CSS and bundles. I have read several and I find firebug very
useful, but I have no idea where to look next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your bundle code with this.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mobile/css")
        .Include("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css",
                 "~/Content/Mobile/jquery.mobile*"));
```

This should load your files without explicitly doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Your right this did work!    Thanks....

The strange thing is that the following did not work:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mobile/css")
    .Include("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css",
             "~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-{version}.js",
             "~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-{version}.js",
             "~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.structure-{version}.js",
             "~/Content/Mobile/css/"));
```

I understand why your example works...but don't understand why mine doesn't ... unless the version tag does not work like I expect it to....

Also I found out the jquery 1.9.1 is much different from 1.7.1 for this I had to do the following:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

this works....using your example I will figure out a wild card pattern to include this as well.

Comment: yes, I have also experienced similar issues with bundles which I have simply failed to understand, sometimes it just doesnt work the way we expect it to, no idea why.

Comment: I am also wondering about the default bundles....both the script and the style....I am wondering if the order the ones that are using wild carding doesn't always work.... For now I have decide not to use the bundles (during development)....when I get closer to release I figure I will create some custom bundles....This appears to be a nice idea that needs some work...again thanks for the insight....now on to the next problem.